# Ldapjs can't connect with a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldapjs

So I just want to create a connection to my LDAP server:

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://192.168.200.35:389'
});
```

But no matter what I'll input for the url:

```
TypeError: ldap://192.168.200.35:389 is an invalid LDAP url (scope)
```

Connecting with the Apache Direct Studio is working fine.
I'll also receive a runtime warning:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/build' in 'C:\...\node_modules\dtrace-provider'
```

Has anyone a fix for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dtrace-provider](https://github.com/chrisa/node-dtrace-provider) doesn't support Windows (and hence ldapjs which is build on top of dtrace also doesn't support Windows OS):

> This libusdt-based Node.JS module supports 64 and 32 bit processes on
>   Mac OS X and Solaris-like systems such as illumos or SmartOS. As more
>   platform support is added to libusdt, those platforms will be
>   supported by this module. See libusdt's status at:

Comment: Well, I didn't expect that. What alternative to `ldapjs` would you suggest?

Comment: I can't recommend any, but the following two seem popular enough to give them a try:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth and 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

Comment: The above mentioned two lib as well not working. can you suggest if anything which resolve above issue.

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A I can't recommend any but from microsoft official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal

Answer (score 0):

In node_modules/ldapjs/lib/url.js we need to do the following changes, after the changes it working fine.

**Error:**

```
parsedURL = new url.URL(urlStr)
```

**Solution:**

```
parsedURL = new url.parse(urlStr)
```